# Accessing List in Lightning components

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I generated a list earlier on in the code and stored it.

```
<aura:attribute name="voiceContactList" type="List"/>
```

```
contactList: Proxy
    [[Handler]]: Object
        [[Target]]: Array(1)
            0: {firstName: 'Ktest2', firstName2: 'Ktest3', LastName: 'Test2', LastName2: 'Test3', streetAddress: '911 SomeTrail Trail', …}
            length: 1 [[Prototype]]: Array(0) [[IsRevoked]]: false
```

The list is there in `contactList` but I haven't been able to access this list.

`console.log('contact = '+ contactList);`

Just shows it as `[object,object]`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strange syntax you see is because the Lightning LockerService has wrapped your object in a `Proxy`. This makes it inaccessible to anything other than your own javascript context.

To access in the console, you can JSON stringify:

```
console.log('contact = '+ JSON.stringify(component.get("v.contactList")));
```

Also see note, to access the attribute, you must use the component getter syntax `component.get("v.yourvarname")`.

To turn into a javascript variable in your controller or helper, do this:

```
let contacts = component.get("v.contactList");
```

If you examined this in the console you would see this is still a Proxy object, but if you attempted to access a property, it would be available, ie:

```
let fname = contacts[0].firstName;
```

Would work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Using `+` when either side is a string, causes `toString` to be called on the other parameter, because JavaScript presumes you want string concatenation.

By way of example:

```
let x = 1 + '1' // '11'
let y = 1 + 1 // 2
```

Use `,` instead to make them separate parameters:

```
console.log('contacts', contactList);
```

This will give you a more desirable output, especially if you're using the new [Lightning Web Security](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.security_lwsec_intro) feature.

Comment: That's a nice insight. Reason I didn't suggest that they were using Web Security was because I think it's not enabled for Aura components. But I like that console trick.

Comment: @CasparHarmer Yeah, LWS appears to be LWC only. That's a bummer. I guess one more reason to move to LWC sooner than later.